# jQuery AJAX Wait

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have constructed a PHP file which scrapes a web page (using cURL) to obtain some data, and outputs it to the screen in JSON format.

The target website involves some redirects which temporarily outputs data to my PHP file. Once the redirects have completed successfully, the JSON is presented as expected. The problem that I am encountering is that when I try to access the JSON using jQuery's `$.ajax()` method, it sometimes returns the incorrect data, because it isn't waiting for the redirects to complete.

My question is if it's possible to tell the AJAX request to wait a certain number of seconds before returning the data, thus allowing time for the redirects in the PHP script to execute successfully?

**Please note that there is no cleaner solution for the page scrape, the redirects are essential and have to be outputted to the screen for the scraping to complete.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always `timeout` in the settings.

[jQuery docs:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> timeout Number
>
> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will
> override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup().
> The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made;
> if several other requests are in progress and the browser
> has no connections available, it is possible for a request
> to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below,
> the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if
> the request times out; accessing any object members may
> throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP
> requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will
> run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

Comment: But `timeout` only specifies the max time that jQuery should spend waiting for a response. The problem I am having is that jQuery is getting the data too early (i.e. before the redirects on the PHP have completed). Essentially, I want to 'wait' for a set amount time, until any redirects on the PHP have been executed.

Comment: How do those redirects work? Generally, the Ajax call will only terminate when your request is done; if redirects happen later, that will not be part of the same request as I understand it. Are those HTTP temp redirects (Status 302 Found) or…?

Comment: The page being requested is JSP. The redirect on the page is simply a `<meta>` refresh. I believe this is used to generate a new Request ID, and then return the results in the same dynamic JSP. I need to wait for the refreshing to end, essentially.

Comment: To clarify, as long as the response body is not written completely, the call should not return. If the PHP page at no point finishes loading (check with accessing it directly in the browser…), the `ajax()` call should not quit either?

Comment: That's precisely what I though too. I have put it on a server so you can see execution: http://ben-major.co.uk/labs/ajax-problem/enlistment.php?asn=34886320

Comment: OK, so you're outputting the redirects from the PHP to the screen, somehow, before you reach your "final destination" URL?

Comment: OK, The first time there's a browser refresh immediate most of the time, second time's the charm. Why do you do that? (Update, more helpful hopefully): Why can't you handle the redirects entirely inside the PHP and only just return the data that you receive when they're finished?

Comment: The data is freely available here > http://aad.archives.gov/aad/series-description.jsp?s=3360

Comment: The JSP this is querying first displays a "Please wait, we're searching" page, and then serves up the results. The second refresh you see is once the search has returned. There's no way of avoiding the first refresh, since it creates a unique search ID for caching purposes.

Comment: I understand that that's how the target page works, but what forces you to expose that to the browser? What I want to say is, why not run those requests inside of one PHP invocation and only then write results to *your* output. The Ajax will see the results of a request of your PHP page, so if you hide the details of your target inside the PHP page's works, the Ajax call won't notice them.

Comment: Because when I try to do that, I am not able to retrive the unique search ID that I need.

Comment: You mean the JSESSIONID cookie? If so, see my pseudo-code in the edited reply.

Comment: No, it's not the JSESSIONID. If you look at the first record that the sample search returns, the link to view the record contains a URL parameter of rid=######

Comment: OK, so it's about `displayPartialRecords` … but I don't see why you would have to output anything about the 'please wait' refreshes to *your* client just because you need to extract the RID from the final response?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8398/discussion-between-bernd-haug-and-benm)

Answer (score 0):

You should use  promise() in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could always store the result of your ajax call and then wait for the redirects to finsih, i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(e)
    {
         var wait = setTimeout(function(){ doSomethingWithData(e.data); }, 5000); //5 sec
    }

})
```

Alternatively, you could set up an Interval to check if something happened (redirect finished) every x amount of ms. I'm assuming your redirects are letting you know they completed?

Answer (score 0):

```
http://examples.hmp.is.it/ajaxProgressUpdater/

$i=0;
while (true)
{
if (self::$driver->executeScript("return $.active == 0")) {
break;
}

if($i == 20) {
break;
}

$i++;`enter code here`
echo $i;
usleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: This code work proper for me... For WaitForAjaxComplete   :)